# background process

Tags: php, system, exec

I never used system commands so I would need a little help running a php background process:

1. Can I run an `exec()` command on a shared server environment?
2. Is it possible not to wait for it to finish in the file I am running it from?
3. Can I use parameters to pass to this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It depends on the server configuration.
2. Maybe if you use screen.
3. You can use parameters as you would run the command from command line.
   http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score -1):

1 Try and find out

2 use `/dev/null`

3 `exec('php -f '.ROOT_PATH.'/index.php '.$this->['param'].' '.$param.' '.$param.' "'.preg_replace('/"/', '\"', serialize($array))."\" > /dev/null &");`